# Как организовать перевод даты?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь организовать перевод даты через echo \Yii::t('app', 'Today is {0, date}', time()); из вот этой [статьи](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-i18n/) у меня возникли два вопроса.

1 Необходимо ли для даты организовавть документ app.php для даты или нет?

2 Как оргнанизовать app.php  для даты ну на приримаре тогоже матра и января?

Comment: Вроде по стандарту у пхп даты по русски будут отображаться если в `ini` включено `extension=php_intl.dll`       а во фреймворке указано включена русская локализация

Comment: тоесть это в php.ini должно быть? ну на локальном серевере не страшно а если на сервак переносить это с провайдером азбираться надо. Охохошиньки хохо

Comment: Они у всех по умолчанию уже включены.... редко бывают случаи..... а вообще под себя обычно проще VPS/VDS взять, всё настроить там чисто под себя как удобно и как нужно и не париться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на опенсеревер были выключены но включение не помогло я даже через Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'ru-RU';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($post->date,"MMMM") ставлю все равно английские выдает причем и в конфиге локализация 'language' => 'ru-RU', стоит почему вот в чем вопрос

Comment: Видимо не там правите в опенсерере...или не у той версии php.. у опенсервера их же несколько....у меня усё работает вот.....плюс у фреймворка в конфиге (а при смене языка тоже не забыть) еще у форматтера вам надо бы задать язык наверное....вот у меня в конфиге написано: `formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:d F Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:j F, H:i',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i:s',
            'defaultTimeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
            'locale' => 'ru-RU'
        ]`

Comment: Все на много проше я ответ оформил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в main.php в конфиге , у меня advanсed  стоит, кроме

```
'language' => 'ru-RU',
```

надо писать

```
'sourceLanguage' =>'ru-RU',
```

Comment: Почитайте http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/yiit-i-iskhodnyy-jazyk-dlja-soobscheyniy  .......`'sourceLanguage' =>'ru-RU'` дает проблемы........ кстати у меня стоит `'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',` ...... что-то с настройками нашаманено у вас ........ я почему-то все еще уверен что не тот php вы правили)